# How to make the x axis of a histogram non-numeric

Tags: r, histogram

I'm looking at a subset of data and I'm looking only within one column and I am breaking the rows of that column down into three sections.  Each of the three sections has a mean and I want to be able to display each of the three means on a histogram.  I would like to have the histogram to have "MeanA", "MeanB", and "MeanC" on the x-axis with the actual mean values on the y-axis so that I can visually see the difference between the 3 means.

I have tried this:

> hist(c(MeanA, MeanB, MeanC), breaks=15)

But it gives me frequency on the y-axis which is useless to me because they are all 1. And the x-axis is very messy because all three of the means are very close in value to one another. Is there a way to annotate the x-axis with only the names of "MeanA", "MeanB", and "MeanC", while putting a numeric range on the y-axis?

Comment: You  may want to consider using `barplot` instead.

Comment: I'm not sure why so many people say they want a histogram when they actually want a barplot.

Comment: In the event you are actually making a histogram in the future, the argument xaxt="n" will suppress the x labels. Then `axis(1, at=seq(1,3,1), labels=c("MeanA","MeanB","MeanC")`, That said I agree with @Benjamin, check out `barplot`

Comment: @Roland I feel like there's a lot of low quality writing and teaching on that topic (histogram vs bar plot), so without being explicitly taught the difference they will be easy to confuse, visually.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you need a `barplot`, you can use `ggplot2` like this:

```
# Random data
df <- data.frame(
group = c(rep(c("Group A", "Group B", "Group C"),each=100)),
values = c(rnorm(100, 1, 1), rnorm(100, 2, 1), rnorm(100, 3, 1))
)

# Plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df) + 
geom_bar(aes(group, values, fill = group), stat = "summary", fun.y = "mean") +
ylab("Mean") +
xlab("") +
theme_minimal() +
theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]